# How to reverse a USB firmware patching tool for another device?

Tags: ida, debugging

I have a USB device from a vendor (TRENDnet) that has the exact same chipset as a QNAP device with an available firmware patching tool.

It's my belief that this firmware patching tool should work perfectly fine with my TRENDnet device.

However, when I run the firmware patching tool, it reports that it cannot find a suitable device and exits.

I believe the firmware patching tool is looking for specific USB `VIDs` and `PIDs` to detect
**valid** USB devices. I've extracted from the drivers that these are the valid `VID/PID` combinations.

```
VID_2ECA - PID_C101
VID_2ECA - PID_C102
VID_0B95 - PID_2790
VID_0B95 - PID_2791
VID_1C04 - PID_0015
VID_1C04 - PID_0016
```

I would like to see if it's possible to inject additional `PID/VID` values into the tool to allow my device to be detected and have the firmware upgraded.

I've tried searching for the various `VID/PID` combos in a hex editor to no avail, and have also tried to decompile the app using IDA Free with no success (mainly because I have no idea what I am doing).

Can someone either look at the file or offer some advice of what to do look for/try next?

The firmware patching tool can be downloaded from this [link](https://www.qnap.com/en-us/download?model=qna-uc5g1t&category=firmware).

The tool is named `aqusbupdate.exe` and it reads in `QNAP_QNA-UC5G1T_FW_3.1.6.bin` when passed in as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a quick research - if you're getting `[!] No devices found` prompt this is likely due to the updater getting no adapter results with the below [WQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wql?view=powershell-5.1) query:

[image: aqusbupdate.exe's adapter WQL query]

I guess checking if you have `Aq_UsbNetAdapter` [WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-start-page) objects available would be a starting point.

Comment: Can I ask how you were able to convert the .exe to this code view?

Comment: This is 32-bit IDA Pro's pseudocode view, IDA Free should have the decompiler [available as SaaS](https://hex-rays.com/ida-free/); decompile the file, after IDA finishes the analysis double-click `sub_41D3D0` function and press `F5` to access the decompiled pseudocode view